# Aurora rds -> MySQL rds cross region replication

Tags: mysql, replication, amazon-aurora

I am looking to do cross region replication. I know exactly how to do it but want to do it in safest way possible from a networking perspective. I will call set external master but I don’t want my instances to be publicly accessible.

How does amazon do cross region replication via control panel securely without using publicly accessible option for rds

The reason I am using MySQL on other region is cost savings. Since it isn’t aurora to aurora I need to use set external master and setup replication manually.

Do I just put everything in same VPC?

Comment: How about setting up a multi account multi region VPC peering as long as you ensure the IP ranges in two or more setups do not overlap?

Comment: How would I setup a multi region VPC? These are in the same account

Comment: Yes, that can be an option as in all AWS services in the same VPC as long as you can take care of no overlaps in CIDRs. Just curious here, it seems to me that you are provisioning MySQL as just your backup. Is this a passive backup or all your reads in this region will be served from this instance?

Comment: I use the passive region just for reads and not at a huge volume. I am almost thinking that an Aurora Global Database might be a good option. Then I don't have to worry about manually setting up replication

Comment: In my opinion, given you've called out that you do not expect intensive reads - global database may be an overkill.

Comment: What would your recommendation be? All I need the other region for is disaster recovery. Right now I use vanilla mysql rds with a read replica another region. In my primary region, I use Multi-AZ for mysql. I tested Aurora and it is 20-30% faster on queries I tested and I don't have to worry about disk space.The cost is twice as and I can't use a less than an m4.large in the secondary region and I don't need all that power. I was going to use a mysql read replica in the ohio region and replicate from Aurora manually but would need to reconfigure networks as I can't use VPC peering

Comment: can't use VPC peering because both regions VPCs share the same private ip address ranges and would be a pain to rebuild everything

Comment: There lies your answer. If not VPC peering than Aurora global database than.

Comment: If I do re-setup network in Ohio for VPC peering then I could connect to Virgina Region from Ohio region for replication? Right now I have mysql cross region replication from Virgina --> Ohio but it is managed via AWS control panel. If I do peering that would solve issue of replication?

Comment: How is replication that amazon manages work find with VPS's sharing IP addresses

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187288/discussion-between-raunak-jhawar-and-chris-muench).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you want to create read replica in cross region. Try this

https://medium.com/tensult/cross-account-and-cross-region-rds-mysql-db-replication-part-1-55d307c7ae65

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/cross-region-read-replicas-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql/